# What is the space that we live in?

Tags: manifolds, physics

Not sure if this question is trivial to some experts; but what is the three dimensional space that we live in? If this question is too difficult to describe, can we at least tell its topology? Is it $\mathbb{R}^3$, or $S^3$? Could it be non-orientable?

Comment: Very poetic title. I like that. As far as I know, there isn’t even consensus about its dimension.

Comment: I think, however, that the question is off-topic here.

Comment: As I understand the theory described briefly in this article http://www.nytimes.com/2003/10/08/science/08CND-COSMOS.html is that the universe is a 3-manifold whose presentation is a dodecahedron.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe

Comment: Excellent question. I attended a very nice [talk](https://math.boisestate.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/f08_7.pdf) about it a few years ago by Mike Hitchman on precisely this topic. He calls it *Cosmic topology*, and has a [book](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-With-Introduction-Cosmic-Topology/dp/0763754579) on the subject. In his talk he explained, among other things, that our best current measurements are not precise enough to settle the question unambiguously.

Comment: At human scale, it certainly approximates $\mathbb R^3$, because that is our intuitive model for it.

Comment: Three-dimensional? Following string theory, the universe can be even 20-dimensional (and we are just perceiving a section of it). In that case, one section of a very high dimension manifold (if it is actually a manifold) can't tell much about the actual geometry or topology of it.

Comment: For a different approach to Hitchman's, with emphasis on string theory, take a look at **The shape of inner space**, a book by Fields medalist Shing-Tung Yau and Steve Nadis.

Comment: And for a much earlier discussion of the topic, look at Riemann's "inagural lecture" at Gottingen (http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Geom/WKCGeom.html). Section III addresses your question in part. Spivak's Differential Geometry book (volume 2) begins with this lecture and then spends several chapters on the topic "What was Riemann actually saying?"

Comment: By the most plausible way of construing this question, it would belong to physics rather than to mathematics.

Comment: This is a question in physics (cosmology in particular), not math.

Comment: The answer is "imaginary and irrational one".

Answer (score 1):

The universe in Dante's *Divine Comedy* is homeomorphic to $S^3$ with Lucifer and God sitting at the poles and the Earth's surface being the 2-dimensional "equator".

For us in the 21st century things are rather more complicated. I think (but I'm not really sure) that according to GRT the Universe has a (large) open set which is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4=\Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R i$